# Перемещение внутри списка

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать на jquery, существует список

```
                <ul>
                    <li id="456"></li>
                    <li id="34"></li>
                    <li id="786"></li>
                    <li id="76"></li>
                    <li id="5"></li>
                </ul>
```

как перемещать строки между собой, li с id 5 поставить на первое место, а id с номером 456 сместить на строчку ниже.

Comment: Парсить всё в массив и сортировать по id

Comment: Для перемещений элементов используются методы элементов `insertBefore` и `appendChild`. Если вы хотите поставить последний элемента на первое место, нужно выполнить: `$ul.insertBefore($li_id5, $li_id456)`. Но этот пример без использования jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("ul").children().last().insertBefore($('ul').children().first());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul>
    <li id="456">456
    </li>
    <li id="34">34
    </li>
    <li id="786">786
    </li>
    <li id="76">76
    </li>
    <li id="5">5
    </li>
</ul>
```